# SocketIO - processing data before broadcasting

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am currently having a problem with a small Node.JS application. It is extremely similar to, for example, the Socket.IO sample chat application: whenever an user sends data to the server, I need to process the data and then broadcast it to all users. However, the way data is processed depends on the user that receives it. I tried altering the `Socket#emit` method (in order to process the data before sending it) for each socket, but the broadcasting doesn't use it. Is there any way I can get this solved?

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT

Here is what I'd tried ():

```
var io = require('socket.io');

io.use(function(socket, next) {
    var old_emit = socket.emit;

    socket.emit = function() {
        // do something with the data (arguments[1] in this case)
        // the processing of the data depends on a value that is
        // unique to each connection, and can't be sent over to the client

        old_emit.apply(socket, arguments);
    }
});
```

I tried the code above because I thought, initially, that broadcasting would call `emit` somewhere else for each connection.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Posting code will help us to understand

Comment: pmverma, I have tried overloading the `Socket#emit` method, as I said in the question. I will try to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do,
There is no any "io( )" like function.You are doing it wrong.

BTW, to process data.
From sample chat application,

```
// when the client emits 'new message', this listens and executes
socket.on('new message', function (data) {

 //call a function which you want to process data
 var newData = messageProcessingFunc(data);
//and then broadcast it.

 // we tell the client to execute 'new message'
 socket.broadcast.emit('new message', {
    username: socket.username,
    message: newData 
    });
});
```

Comment: I apologise. I meant to use `io.use` which adds a middleware to the socket.io. And this code snippet won't work for me, as the message processing function depends on data that's unique to each user that's connected to the server